# Windows 2016 Support for install4j

Tags: install4j

Util class has a isWindowsXXX() method for every windows release. We need to support Windows 2016. When will com.install4j.api.Util.isWindows2016() be supported for install4j? The online docs does not show this method to be supported yet.

Comment: I've added it to our issue tracker.

Comment: thanks. Is there an ETA for when it will be available?

Comment: It's scheduled for 6.1.6, but in the meantime you can easily check the os.version system property.

Comment: got it. thank you.

Comment: On my Windows 2016 machine, os.name shows as "Windows NT (unknown)" and os.version shows as 10.0.. So I guess the check should be something like os.name contains Windows and version == "10.0" ?

Comment: That would check for Windows 10 as well. You will have to wait for a Java version that has a correct os.name property (i.e. that contains the string "2016"). An API method in install4j will not do that differently.